# PIP install shows syntax error when specified version

Tags: python, django, pip, django-1.4

When tried to install any dependency with specific version using PIP I am getting following error:

```
(myvenv) D:\Project\on-staging>pip install Fabric==1.4.3
Collecting Fabric==1.4.3
  Using cached Fabric-1.4.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-39la41_8\Fabric\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        from fabric.version import get_version
      File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-39la41_8\Fabric\fabric\version.py", line 104
        print get_version('all')
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-39la41_8\Fabric\
```

Doing `pip install Fabric` works fine though.

Comment: You're trying to run Python 2 code in Python 3. They are not compatible.

Comment: Which `Python` version are you using? `Fabric` is only compatible with `Python2.5` to `Python 2.7`

Comment: Try using Fabric3, which is Python 3 compatible

Answer (score 0):

Use python 2.7 within virtual environment